# Is there anyway I can prevent an application from knowing that my developer option in on?

Tags: developer-options

I use one application that doesn't run while developer option is turned on. Is there any way that I can disguise the application the developer option is turned off? (I know there is a way in rooted phone but can you help me to do same in an unrooted phone)

Comment: yes there is a way - turn off developer options